# Concatenation of two fields of two files

Tags: shell-script

I have two files : called `t1.txt` and `t2.txt`. The contents are :

#### t1.txt

```
a
b
c
```

#### t2.txt

```
ab
bc
cd
```

Now I want to merge these two files line by line into t3.txt so that the t3.txt should look like :

#### t3.txt

```
aab
bbc
ccd
```

Please help in getting the output using shell script.

Answer (score 3):

#### paste & sed

There are more efficient ways but here's a quick and dirty method using `paste` and `sed`.

```
$ paste -d":" t1.txt t2.txt | sed 's/://g'
aab
bbc
ccd
```

The above joins the 2 files like this:

```
a:ab
b:bc
c:cd
```

And the `sed` removes the `:`.

#### just paste

You can forgo using the `sed`, it's a bit redundant by telling `paste` to use nothing as a delimiter when joining the files:

```
$ paste -d "" t1.txt t2.txt
aab
bbc
ccd
```

#### awk

You can also use `awk` to do this:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next} {print a[FNR] $0}'  t1.txt t2.txt
aab
bbc
ccd
```

This loops through the 1st file, `t1.txt`, and stores it in an array, `a[FNR]`. The `FNR` is the index into that array based on the line number each line was in, in file `t1.txt`. Afterwards, it loops through the 2nd file, `t2.txt`, and prints the line corresponding line from the 1st file along with the 2nd file.

#### join & awk & nl

This method is a little convoluted but works and makes the heavy lifting less complicated when using `awk`, in terms of what's going on.

```
$ join <(nl t1.txt) <(nl t2.txt)|awk '{print $2 $3}'
aab
bbc
ccd
```

The `nl ...` commands produce versions of the test files with line numbers:

```
$ nl t1.txt 
     1  a
     2  b
     3  c
```

The `join` command then uses these line numbers as the piece of data which is common to both files, so it can join on it.

```
$ join <(nl t1.txt) <(nl t2.txt)
1 a ab
2 b bc
3 c cd
```

The `awk` is used at the end to extract the 2nd and 3rd columns from above.

#### pr & awk

The little used `pr` command can also be used to join the files using its merge switch `-m`.

```
$ pr -t -m  t1.txt t2.txt  | awk '{print $1 $2}'
aab
bbc
ccd
```

Comment: `paste -d ''` is not portable

Comment: The `join` one will not work with many versions of `join` as `join` expects input lexically sorted on keys. Note that `nl` doesn't number every line.

Answer (score 1):

```
paste -d '\0' t1.txt t2.txt > t3.txt
```

No it doesn't include NUL characters between the two files.

Yes, it is standard (POSIX) and portable, and the most efficient you can get.

Answer (score 0):

From BASH shell try to run (without any additional text processing tools):

```
exec 3< t1.txt
exec 4< t2.txt

while read l1 <&3 && read l2 <&4; do
    echo ${l1}$l2
done > t3.txt
```

Comment: Note that it assumes the data contains no blank, wildcard or backslash characters, and lines don't start with `-`. It's also going to be terribly inefficient especially if using `bash` unless the files are small.