# Merging Two Files columns in order

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I want to merge two files.

Files A.txt

```
001;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr
002;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr
003;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr
004;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr
005;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr
```

.
Second File B.txt

```
001;mno
002;mno
003;mno
004;mno
005;mno
```

to have a text file C.txt

```
001;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
```

I am able to merge these two files but I don't know how to insert the output
from file B `mno` before `pqr`.

Comment: Does this have to be done with awk? I know you tagged it as such but there are simpler ways.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86849/concatenation-of-two-fields-of-two-files/86851#86851. I'm very tempted to mark this Q as a duplicate, there are literally dozens of examples on the site that show how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join` will print each line of  **sorted** input files that have the same first *(by default) field. So, setting the field delimiter (`-t`) to `;` you get:

```
$ join -t\; A.txt B.txt 
001;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr;mno
002;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr;mno
003;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr;mno
004;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr;mno
005;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr;mno
```

Combining that with `awk` to switch the field positions around:

```
$ join -t\; A.txt B.txt | 
    awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '{k=$NF; $NF=$(NF-1); $(NF-1)=k; print;}'
001;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
002;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
003;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
004;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
005;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
```

Comment: You can tell `join` to print the fields in a different order to begin with. That won't work for variable numbers of fields, of course, but it saves a process if it's a predictable file.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `join`

```
join -t\; -o0,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.2,1.6 a.txt b.txt
```

`-t\;` uses semicolons as a field separator, and the `-o` list tells it which fields to print in what order. This will not print lines in either file with no match in the other; to get that you can add `-a1` (for the first file) or `-a2` (for the second).

Comment: Kevin awsome never thought of doing it in such an easy way.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
awk -F';' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$NF;next}{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if($i<a[$1]){
            printf("%s;",$i)
        } else {
            printf("%s;%s",a[$1],$i)
        }
    }
    print ""}' B.txt A.txt
```

Output:

```
001;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
002;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
003;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
004;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
005;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
```

Comment: @user62687 - if this A solved your problem would you kindly mark it as the accepted A so other users of the site know your issue's been resolved? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So this is what I used to get the source material:

```
cat <<F1 >/tmp/f1 ; cat <<F2 >/tmp/f2
$(for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do { \
    printf "00%s" $i ; printf ";%s" \
        abc def ghi jkl pqr ; echo ; } ; done)
 F1
 $(for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do {\ 
    printf "00%s" $i ; echo ";mno" ; } ; done)
 F2
```

It supplies:

```
001;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr
002;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr
003;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr
004;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr
005;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr
001;mno
002;mno
003;mno
004;mno
005;mno
```

I tested this in various ways, and this is the resulting command:

```
% sed -e 'R /tmp/f2' /tmp/f1 |\
    sed -r 'N;s/(.*)(;[^;]*)\n[^;]*(.*)/\1\3\2/'
```

This is [GNU `sed` only](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-R-_0028read-line_0029-command-203) - because GNU offers the `R` function we can read in a separate file line-by-line in lockstep with our input. This means no branching and no looping. In this way, I expect `sed` would work more efficiently than `awk` because it wouldn't have to read the contents entirely into memory before operating and it can operate on a live stream.

I attempted to make this work without the `|pipe` and second `sed` invocation, but because `sed` appends */tmp/f2* to its own `stdout` nothing I tried allowed me to edit in stream without the `|pipe`. `sed` first collates the two files in stream and edits the result on the other end of the `|pipe`.

Anyway, one `|pipe` though and it's still streamed, but you need two `sed`s . Run the above `sed` command on your data and:

```
OUTPUT
> 001;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
> 002;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
> 003;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
> 004;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
> 005;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
```

Here's how it works:

```
sed -r 'N;s/(.*)(;[^;]*)\n[^;]*(.*)/\1\3\2/'
```

- ***N*** because we already know that `sed` is appending each successive line from `f2` to those in `f1` the very first thing we do after receiving a line is to pull in the `N`ext one.
- ***s*** having joined the two lines we need in pattern space, we begin the `s`earch and replace function

  ***001;abc;def;ghi;jkl***;pqr\n001;mno
- ***\1 (.*)*** first tell `sed` to `(` group * everything it `)` finds from the left-most portion of the pattern space into the `\1` back-reference until...

  001;abc;def;ghi;jkl***;pqr***\n001;mno
- ***\2 (;[^;]*)\n*** it encounters a string consisting of a...

  - ; semicolon then ...
  - ***[^;]**** a string consisting entirely of ^no ;semicolons immediately followed by
  - ***\n*** the `\n`ewline character added when we pulled in `f2`'s line with `N` and which will be discarded
  - ***()*** In this way we back reference the `(` last semicolon delimited field `)` from the line in `f1` to `\2`
- ***[^;]**** beginning with `f2`'s line we search through and discard all characters until we encounter a semicolon, and

  001;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr\n001***;mno***
- ***\3 (.*)*** we store everything that remains in the `\3` backreference
- ***\1\3\2*** once we've split out the string as we require all that remains is to put it back together in the right order, so we insert `\3` before `\2` and we're through with this search replace cycle until we're fed a new line

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$NF=a[$1]FS$NF' fileb filea
```

```
$ cat filea
001;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr
002;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr
003;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr
004;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr
005;abc;def;ghi;jkl;pqr
```

```
$ cat fileb     # Intentionally modified fields to show they map correctly
001;mno
002;nno
003;qno
004;fno
005;sno
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$NF=a[$1]FS$NF' fileb filea
001;abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno;pqr
002;abc;def;ghi;jkl;nno;pqr
003;abc;def;ghi;jkl;qno;pqr
004;abc;def;ghi;jkl;fno;pqr
005;abc;def;ghi;jkl;sno;pqr
```